# Gesture Events and StageWebView

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, flex-spark

Greetings!  I have a Flex 4.5 Mobile project rolling, and I've hit a pretty crazy snag.  I'm using a StageWebView object to render web pages, embedded within the rest of my spark layouts.  I'm trying to add a gesture event to the component that contains the StageWebView, but since the StageWebView object doesn't belong to the Flex stack (it inherits from EventDispatcher, not UIComponent) all of my events seem to be getting eaten.  Any mouse based event (click, gesture, etc) doesn't seem to register, and I'm not sure how to get around it.  The gesture events work if I use the area where the browser is not rendered.  How can I get the gesture event from the outer SkinnableContainer?

StageWebView Reference:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html

UIComponent Wrapped StageWebView:

http://soenkerohde.com/2010/11/air-mobile-stagewebview-uicomponent/

Thanks!

Comment: Side note:  I have attempted to set a global event on my main MXML page, with useCapture set to true.  Events occurring on the StageWebView are still not captured.

Comment: I decided to open a bug with adobe on this one: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-30564

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have to wire up the gesture events yourself, just doing a quick digging in `UIComponent.as`, it has these:

```
[Event(name="touchInteractionStarting", type="mx.events.TouchInteractionEvent")]
[Event(name="touchInteractionStart", type="mx.events.TouchInteractionEvent")]
[Event(name="touchInteractionEnd", type="mx.events.TouchInteractionEvent")]
```

Comment: Actually just realised that there are gesture based events in `InteractiveObject` too...

Comment: The holding control that I'm using to render the StageWebView is an instance of UIComponent - even though it defines those events, the event is never getting raised.  It would require handling a similar event from the StageWebView component and passing that up through the UIComponent implementation.

Comment: Hmm, I see, so probably `StageWebView` is absorbing all the interactions :( the only other idea I have is messier, having a transparent `UIComponent` (well I guess probably actually a `Sprite`) on top of `StageWebView` which bubbles simple interactions but captures gestures.

Comment: Been there tried that :-) From the Adobe docs - "StageWebView content draws over the top of any display list content. There is no way to control the drawing order of multiple StageWebView objects."  Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: OK then, I guess this is important / annoying enough to file as a bug? http://bugs.adobe.com/

Answer (score 0):

it's not a bug, from what i understand any mouse interaction over a stagewebview means an interaction with the html currently loaded in itself. you should capture events there and trigger it back to the swf.

surely there are some jquery plugins or something that have gestures to help achieving that.
 it's a bit of a bummer that you cant overlay stuff over them though.